# Sort a query based on an association 2 or more levels deep

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have the following models

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :counter_cache => true
  belongs_to :subtopic      
end


class Subtopic < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :posts, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, :through => :subtopics
  has_many :subtopics, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

In the posts/index page, I want to add click-able sorting to the column titles.  This is fine, except that I display some information two levels deep:

- post attributes

  - subtopic name

    - category name

I want the "Category" column of the table to be click-able, such that I can display all posts sorted by their category.  Unfortunately, when I construct the "order by" part of the query, I can't seem to get anything to work for category name.  I can go one level deep with

```
@posts = Post.includes(:user, :subtopic => :category).paginate(:page =>1, :order => 'subtopics.name ASC')
```

This returns the results I want.  When I try going one level deeper with

```
@posts = Post.includes(:user, :subtopic => :category).paginate(:page =>1, :order => 'subtopic.categories.name ASC')
```

I get `PGError: ERROR:  schema "subtopic" does not exist`.  Pluralizing subtopic gives the same error.  I feel like I'm missing something obvious.  Can someone point it out?

**Side note**: Bad smell alert.  I know.  If you have suggestions on how to make this code cleaner as well, that would be very welcome.  I'm aware of the Law of Demeter, but I don't see how to get the end result I want without breaking it.

---

**UPDATE 8/3**: ActiveRecord or PostgreSQL is causing another error in the controller action.  The following statement is valid in the database console:

```
SELECT * from "posts" LEFT OUTER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "posts"."user_id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "subtopics" ON "subtopics"."id" = "posts"."subtopic_id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "categories" ON "categories"."id" = "subtopics"."category_id" ORDER BY categories.name ASC LIMIT 30;
```

The SQL statement above is *approximately* what's generated from the statement below.  The rails code below is valid in `rails console` but **not** in my controller action for `Post#index`

```
 @posts = Post.includes(:user, :subtopic => :category).paginate(:page =>1, :order => 'categories.category_name ASC', :conditions => ["posts.flags_count < ?", Flag.flag_threshold] )
```

The error: https://gist.github.com/1124135

This error occurs for `:order => 'categories. ...'` and `:order => 'subtopics. ...'` but **not** for `:order => (column in posts)`.  It looks like a problem with the JOIN statement that ActiveRecord generates, but the actual SQL statement looks like it should work to me.

---

**Update 8/4**: When I enable SQL logging in my environment (using [a shell script](https://gist.github.com/1126066)), I can see that the SQL queries that ActiveRecord generates in `rails console` and (a controller in) `rails server` are different.

Specifically, on the server, AR is prepending certain columns with 'post.', such as `posts.users.display_name` instead of `users.display_name`.  This only happens **on the server**, and only when I include in the query `:order => (non-posts column) ASC/DESC`

Comment: For those with a similar problem, I decided to split the second problem into a separate question, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6948966/why-is-this-activerecord-statement-failing-in-server-but-not-console

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string in your order clause is inserted into the resulting SQL pretty much as-is.  So the resulting query turns out to be something like:

```
Select...order by subtopic.categories.name ASC
```

And the database has no idea what that means.  You want to order by 'categories.name ASC'.

**UPDATE**: Ok, now will_paginate is choking on the join.  I would do something like this:

```
@posts = Post.includes(:user, :subtopic => :category).where(["posts.flags_count < ?", Flag.flag_threshold]).order('categories.category_name ASC').paginate(:page =>1)
```

That should get you going.  I would further clean up my controller by moving all of that finder stuff into the model, probably as a scope named 'by_category_order' or something.  Then my controller code would be nice and pretty like:

```
@posts = Post.by_category_order.paginate(:page => params[:page])
```

Comment: Thanks, this was a step in the right direction.  I can get this to work for a SQL statement.  The Ruby equivalent works in `rails console`, but it breaks in the controller.  I updated the post with the new error.

Comment: Hm, if I run that query with `where` in the console, it works fine.  If I put it in my controller, Rails still chokes with the same PGError.  I can even chop off the `paginate` portion at the end and it chokes in the same way.  It's almost like there's a difference between the database in `rails console` and `rails server`...

Comment: Could be. Are both their RAILS_ENVs development?

Comment: Yep, both are development.  `Rails.version` is the same for both at 3.0.9 as well.  I've been able to narrow down the error a little further--I put some details in the post.

Comment: Actually, I think this is going out of the scope of the original question, so I'll make a new one and accept your response as the answer.  Thanks for the help!