# Why is this ActiveRecord statement failing in Server but not Console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have the following query which is failing in `rails s` in a particular controller.  It's not failing in `rails c`.

```
Post.includes(:user).find(:all, :limit => 10, :order => 'users.display_name ASC')
```

In the console it returns the correct data.  In the server, I get this error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  column posts.users.display_name does not exist
LINE 1: ...s_count" AS t0_r7, "posts"."popularity" AS t0_r8, "posts"."u...
                                                             ^
```

The query is long and I'll just include a few relevant snippets

```
: SELECT  "posts"."id" AS t0_r0, "posts"."post_content" AS t0_r1, 
...    
"posts"."popularity" AS t0_r8, "posts"."users.display_name" AS t0_r9,
"posts"."subtopics.name" AS t0_r10, "posts"."categories.category_name" 
AS t0_r11
...
FROM "posts" LEFT OUTER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "posts"."user_id" 
ORDER BY users.display_name ASC LIMIT 10
```

In the controller, the query generates 3 extra terms.  The query labels them as t0_r9, t0_r10, and t0_r11.  It seems like AR is adding this because I'm referencing those specific columns in the view of that controller action.  I don't see why it'd do that, though, as that's the purpose of using `includes`.

Comment: I suspect I may have uncovered a bug, either with AR or the PG gem, but I'd like other eyes to verify this.

Comment: Are you using any gems, plugins, or monkey patches that might be affecting the query generation? That's usually my problem when I run into weird issues like this.

Comment: No monkey patches or plugins for sure.  The only gem I was using related to this query was will_paginate, but I've reproduced the error without using that at all (as in the post).  The PG gem is just an ActiveRecord adapter for PostgreSQL.  Wouldn't any gems or plugins be present and loaded when I run this from the console?

Comment: Usually, especially now that rails uses Bundler.require. Most cases where I've seen these strange inconsistencies happen are when code that only executes during a request specifically requires another ruby file. The file would be loaded in the running server, but not the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the error wasn't in the code I posted.  I had a helper to determine which column to order by.  It looked something like this:

```
valid_names = Post.column_names
valid_names = valid_names.concat(["users.display_name", "subtopics.name",
  "categories.category_name"])

valid_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "popularity"
```

Little did I know that this would actually concatenate the extra terms onto `Post.column_names`.  I fixed this issue by making a copy with `Post.column_names.clone` and this resolved the issue.

I feel pretty silly making this mistake, but hopefully this will help someone else who's running into the same issue.